# How to reload the component of same URL in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am trying to reload the same url in Angular 2 by using router.navigate but it is not working.
url : http://localhost:3000/landing
Scenario : I am on http://localhost:3000/landing and now I am changing a particular parameter in the page which should reload the page.

Code :

```
let link = ['Landing'];
this.router.navigate(link);
```

Comment: and what happens? DO you get any errors at the moment?

Answer (score 15):

Navigate to some dummy component and then navigate to the component that you want to reload.
//the second parameter _skipLocationChange=true to avoid that url in back button

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyComponent', true);
this.router.navigate(["Landing"]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That really helped.

Comment: @Anish You can also mark it as answer since it solved your problem.

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Do you have another way to deal with it, for me it didn't work.

Comment: @trungk18 I've found that you need to pass in an object, `this.router.navigateByUrl('/Dummy', { skipLocationChange: true })` worked for me.

Comment: I placed the second navigation in a timeout. setTimeout(() => {
                     this.router.navigate(['/Landing']);
                 }, 100);

Answer (score 7):

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
this.router.navigate(["Landing"]));
```

Comment: Why would you copy an existing answer?

Comment: @MaciejJureczko: doesn't look like the same answer to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Well it's not identical but it's a *nearly* identical copy of the highest scoring answer.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko so it's not a copy.

Comment: @MartinPieters - I don't understand why you're taking this to a lexical level but alright...

So... I cannot agree. A copy is *usually* not identical in most meanings and contexts we can imagine. You can have a *bad copy* or a *good copy*. Performing copies *usually* takes into account errors and imperfections. This is a copy with a slight modification. And last of all, I do not think this matters at all. What matters is the intent. Headbozo either ignored all previous content and wrote his answer or he *copied* the best answer and modified it. IMO both make this a candidate for removal.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko Well, the differences are pretty essential. It's a promise flow now and see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396075/how-to-reload-the-component-of-same-url-in-angular-2#comment70457346_39397060). But then, the missing explanation makes this a low-quality answer anyway.

Comment: Maciej is right though it's the identical answer to a comment of the answer on Jan 13 '17, a good 7 months before this post

Comment: This *was* the answer that helped me, though. I forgot using the `then`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement reloading a component by using [PlatformLocation:onPopState](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html#!#onPopState-anchor) and [NgZone:run](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#run-anchor) in the constructor. It was a work around, but atleast it worked the way it was required.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
    private platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
    private ngZone: NgZone) {

    platformLocation.onPopState(() => {
        if(platformLocation.pathname.startsWith("/currentRoute")) {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                console.log("Reloading component");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`onPopState` was used as the reloading was supposed to be triggered on browser back/forward button. Also the check for `pathname` had to be used as the `onPopState` method was getting invoked on back/forward in any routes as the component is injected.