# Angular component in not being loaded when navigating to it for the second time

Tags: angular

In my project I have a parent *shopping* component that includes 2 child components:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item" id="cart"><app-cart></app-cart></div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="categories"><app-categories></app-categories></div>
```

The *categories* component includes a navbar and a router:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
       <span *ngFor="let cat of arrCategories; index as i">
           <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active': i===0}" >
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping/products/{{cat.id}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{cat.name}}</a>
           </li>
        </span>
     </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When clicking on a navbar item I want to load the *products* component into the router, with the id of the selected item.

On ngOnInit of *categories* component I'm loading the products for the first time, and that's work ok:

```
this.router.navigate([`/shopping/products/1`]); //load first category products
```

However, when clicking on navbar item, the url on the address line is being updated correctly, but the products component is not being loaded again.

What is the solution to this issue?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload the component of same URL in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396075/how-to-reload-the-component-of-same-url-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Move the Code that returns product info from id to ngOnChanges() function. Oninit function only runs at component initiating. The second time your code does not execute as it is initialized.

ngOnChanges()- Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.

Reference - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: thanks. how can I cause this data binding to happen so the ngOnChanges will occur?

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly due to the routing issue. 
If the user clicks on the product with ID 3, we want to show the product details page with the overview:

```
localhost:3000/product-details/3/overview
```

When the user clicks "Technical Specs":

```
localhost:3000/product-details/3/specs
```

Our Routes with children would look like:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'product-list', component: ProductList },
  { path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductDetails,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'overview', component: Overview },
      { path: 'specs', component: Specs }
    ]
  }
];
```

So whenever user hits URL with  "localhost:3000/product-details/3/overview" It loads both the parent component[ProductDetails] and the Children component[overview].

Where would the components for these child routes be displayed? Just like in a

```
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
```

Comment: thanks. this is the relevant code of my routes. should it be changes?
{ path: 'shopping', component: ShoppingComponent, children: [
    { path: 'products/:id', component: ProductsComponent },
  ] 
  },

Comment: Can you try moving the router-outlet to the ShoppingComponent?

Comment: I was trying this. the same result.